# Why to prove $f\in H^1\mathbb{(D)}$, it is enough to prove that $f\in L^1(|z|=1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, harmonic-analysis, hardy-spaces

Prove that $$\sqrt{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}$$ is in the Hardy space $H^1(\mathbb{D})$, where we take the principal branch of the square root.

Answer- let $f(z) = \frac{(1+z)^{1/2}}{(1-z)^{1/2}}$ analytic on $|z|<1$ and continuous on $|z|\le 1,z\ne 1$

as $t\to 0$, $f(e^{it}) \sim C t^{-1/2}$

whence $f\in L^1(|z|=1)$.

The Hardy space $H^1(\mathbb{D})$ is the vector space of holomorphic functions $f$ on the open unit disk that satisfy:
$$
\sup_{0\leq r<1}\left(\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}\left|f \left (re^{i\theta}\right )\right| \; \mathrm{d}\theta\right)<\infty.$$
**Question** Why to prove that $f\in H^1\mathbb{(D)}$, it is enough to prove that $f\in L^1(|z|=1)$?

Please give me a reference if possible.

Comment: It's in Katznelson's **An Introduction to Harmonic Analysis**, I think.

Comment: @Hans Engler So what is the statement in it? Please tell me the page number.

Comment: @Hans Engler Thank you. But what is the actual theorem? Is it if $f\in L^p \{|z|=1\}$ then $f \in H^p {\mathbb{(D)}}$ for $p>0$?

Comment: The relevant theorem says that $f \in H^1(S^1)$ iff $f \in L^1(S^1)$ and all negative Fourier coefficients vanish. That, together with the fact that $H^1(D)$ may be identified with $H^1(S^1)$, by taking radial limits. That is Theorem 3.8 in Katznelson's book. You'll have to fill in some details.

Comment: The general theorem is that if $f$ is in the $N^+$ class (read Hardy space theory to understand what $N$ and $N^+$ are but essentially it means $f=BSF$ holds), then $f \in H^p$ iff $f(e^{it}) \in L^p(dt)$ - note that $f(e^{it})$ exists non-tangentially ae (dt) for many functions, including all from $N$ not only $N^+$ but the functions can still be very wild in the unit disc even if $f(e^{it})$ is nicely behaved; in particular since $N^+$ is contained in all hardy spaces, if we know apriori that $f$ is in some Hardy space, then the best Hardy space is determined by the boundary values

Comment: @Conrad Thank you. Please give me a reference.

Comment: in the above example $f^2(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-z}$ is in $N$ as a ratio of bounded analytic functions and is univalent with no zeroes in the disc, hence is outer, so it is in $N^+$; this implies $f$ is in $N^+$ so $f$ is in whatever Hardy space the boundary function is in the corresponding $L^p(dt)$; here actually $f \in H^p, p<2$; Duren basic book about Hardy spaces chapter 2 has all of this and more

Comment: @Conrad Thanks. So is $f(z)=(s-1)\zeta(s)$, $s=\frac{1}{1-z}$ is in $N^+$?

Comment: this is a different question and should be asked as such

Comment: @Conrad Please give a minor hint for this. Thank you.